# Got timeout writing communication packet

Tags: mysql

When executing the select query from an application server the thread got hung up for a long time. When checked in MySQL error log it was mentioned as "Aborted connection. (Got timeout writing communication packets)". If this is related to MySQL net_write_timeout then, what's the batch size mentioned in doc mean?

From MySQL [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_write_timeout):

> **net_write_timeout:**
> The number of seconds to wait for a block to be written to a connection before aborting the write

How can I better understand and diagnose this issue? A little help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You can check this link https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205398/mysql-got-timeout-reading-communication-packets-when-reading-federated-table

Comment: Seems like the above link might be for a different issue (reading vs writing)